# Array.Filter not updating array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

The task is:

> You will be provided with an initial array (the first argument in the
>   destroyer function), followed by one or more arguments. Remove all
>   elements from the initial array that are of the same value as these
>   arguments.

While working through it I found some Array.filter behaviour I'm struggling to understand:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  for (var i = 1; i<arguments.length; i++){
    toDelete = arguments[i];
    arr.filter(isItIn);
  }
  return arr;
}

function isItIn(item, undefined, array){
  return item!=toDelete;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

My intent here was to iterate through items 1+ of the arguments, calling `arr.filter` each time.  `Arr.filter` then calls `isItIn` which checks if the currently examined item is the one I'm searching for.  However, `arr` is being returned unchanged.  When I change `isItIn` to:

```
function isItIn(item, undefined, array){
  return item==1;
}
```

to test, it is still unchanged, however `console.log`s in the original writing of `isItIn` show that it is receiving the arguments correctly (or so far as I've thought to determine at least.

Please note, I've solved the problem through another route, I'm not looking for a solution to the problem, merely an explanation of where my initial code went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and omit the result of it.

You need to assign the result of filter to the former array.

```
arr = arr.filter(isItIn);
```

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        toDelete = arguments[i];
        arr = arr.filter(isItIn);
    }
    return arr;
}

function isItIn(item) {
    return item != toDelete;
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Comment: Oh my...  If you had any idea how long I've stared at that,

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the returned array:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    for (var i = 1; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        toDelete = arguments[i];
        arr = arr.filter(isItIn);
    }
    return arr;
 }
```