# filter an array by property returns unfiltered array

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter

I am trying to filter an array of objects by a property like this

```
if (payment == Payment.CREDIT_CARD) {
  this.currenies.filter((currency: Currency) => currency.isFromEurope === true);
  console.log(this.currencies)
}
```

Initially, currencies array has 135 items, and after filtering the same number of items (at least 30 of them have isFromEurope = true);

Comment: Where is data(`currenies`)?

Comment: `filter` creates a new array, so if you want `this.currencies` to be updated you would assign the filter e.g. `this.currencies = this.currencies.filter(...)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array.Filter not updating array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802480/array-filter-not-updating-array)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation of `Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

i.e. it does not change the original array.

Plus, you have a typo too (`this.currenies`).

It should be like this:

```
if (payment == Payment.CREDIT_CARD) {
  this.currencies = this.currencies.filter((currency: Currency) => currency.isFromEurope === true);
  console.log(this.currencies)
}
```