# Unable to access sub-array in Vue 3 prop object item

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3, dropdown

In a Vue3/InertiaJS project, I am attempting to do a simple dynamic select list population, but I'm having issues reading the props data to populate the dropdown.

```
<script setup>
    import {Head, Link, useForm} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
    import SelectInput from '@/Components/ping/SelectInput.vue'
    import {ref} from 'vue';

      const props = defineProps({
    areas: [
      {
        id:1,
        name:"Club",
        approvers: [
          {
            id:12,
            first_name: "Joe",
            last_name: "Blow"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id:2,
        name:"Adult Small Bore",
        approvers: [
          {
            id:34,
            first_name: "Sam",
            last_name: "Snead"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id:3,
        name:"Appleseed",
        approvers: [
          {
            id:56,
            first_name: "Johhny",
            last_name: "Appleseed"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id:4,
        name:"Archery",
        approvers: [
          {
            id:56,
            first_name: "Jim",
            last_name: "Beam"
          },
          {
            id:56,
            first_name: "Jack",
            last_name: "Daniels"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id:5,
        name:"Armed Women of America",
        approvers: [
          {
            id: 99,
            first_name: "Amelia",
            last_name: "Earhart"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]  
  })

    const form = useForm({
        date: '',
        hours: '',
        area: '',
        reason: '',
        comments: '',
        approver: ''
    });

    let selectApprovers = ref([]);

    function updateApprovers(event) {
        const area = props.areas.filter(area => area.id === parseInt(event.target.value));
        console.log({area});
        selectApprovers.value = area.approvers.map(function (item) {
            return {
                id: item.id,
                name: item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name
            }
        });

       selectApprovers.value = approvers;
    }

    function store() {
        form.post(`/admin/work-hours`)
    }
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="store">
    
                    <select-input v-model="form.area" :error="form.errors.area"
                                class="pb-8 pr-6 w-full lg:w-1/2" label="Area" @change="updateApprovers">
                        <option :value="null" />
                        <option v-for="area in props.areas" :key="area.id" :value="area.id">{{ area.name }}</option>
                    </select-input>
                    <select-input v-model="form.approver" :error="form.errors.approver"
                                class="pb-8 pr-6 w-full lg:w-1/2" label="Approver">
                        <option :value="null" />
                        <option v-for="approver in selectApprovers" :key="approver.id" :value="approver.id">{{ approver.name }}</option>
                    </select-input>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

where the `<select-list>` input is just a [wrapper around](https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm/blob/master/resources/js/Shared/SelectInput.vue) a standard `<select>` element.

The props in the real app are coming from Laravel [via InertiaJS](https://inertiajs.com/how-it-works). The issue I am having is in `updateApprovers()`. This line works fine:

```
const area = props.areas.filter(area => area.id === parseInt(event.target.value));
```

as seen in the `console.log({area})`. However, it errors out at the next line when it tries to read `area.approvers`, and I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "map", area.approvers is undefined
```

I've tried using `value`

```
 selectApprovers.value = area.value.approvers.map(function (item) {
```

but I get the same error. Visual inspection of the props in Vue dev tools shows that the `approvers` array is there; what do I need to change to be able to access it?

I've tried setting up an [sfc playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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), but for some reason it's having issues reading the `v-for` loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array.Filter not updating array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802480/array-filter-not-updating-array)

Comment: No, see the answer below. It was a matter of using `find()` instead of `filter()`, because `filter()` returns an array, whereas `find()` just returns the found item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) always returns another *array*, so this line:

```js
const area = props.areas.filter(area => area.id === parseInt(event.target.value));
```

results in `area` being an array of objects.  Those individual objects may each have an inner `approvers` array, but the `area` array itself has no `approvers` property, which is why `area.approvers.map()` throws an error.

You could do `area[0].approvers.map()`, but I think a more appropriate Array function to use in the first place would be [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to return the first matching *object* which you could then map.

```js
function updateApprovers(event) {
  const area = props.value.areas.find(
    area => area.id === parseInt(event.target.value)
  );
  selectApprovers.value = area.approvers.map(function (item) {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      name: item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: OMG, that has to be one of the most noob JS mistakes, I could make. That did the trick. Thanks!.